# Почему при скроллинге с боку появляется пустое место?

Tags: html, css

Вот мой [сайт](https://bluecoc.online/index.html) (не судите строго, я новенький в этом деле).

Проблема в том, что при скроллинге с боку появляется пустое место:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ф12 и смотри какой элемент вылез за ширину экрана. Он и дает этот скрол по горизонтали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элемент с классом `bac_top2` по ширине больше, чем сама страница. Исправить можно так:

```css
.bac_top2{
 width: 100%;
}
```

P.S. Бедный Ваня

Comment: реально помогло, так что спасибо большое )

Answer (score 1):

Причиной возникновения пустого места является - выход элемента за пределы body. Решить данную проблему можно применив "overflow-x: hidden" к body или уменьшив ширину дочернего элемента выходящий за предел. Рекомендую воспользоваться 2 вариантом, так как использование 1 может повлечь за собой проблемы с отображением контента или дизайна.

Comment: За hidden надо руки отрывать.

Comment: За отрывание рук - соглашусь. Немного подправил ответ)